FluentBit and FluentD Unable to Send Logs to AWS Opensearch Ingestion Service
Trying to send logs from fluentbit to AWS Opensearch Ingestion Pipeline.
Current Setup:
Deployed FluentBit on EKS cluster, attached a service account which has the permission to assume a role (LPM_POC_TEST_1). Used HTTP output plugin, to achieve to goal.
LPM_POC_TEST_1 has the following permission attached:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "osis:Ingest",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}

LPM_POC_TEST_1 has a trust relationship with the FluentBit Role.
Image Used for FluentBit: amazon/aws-for-fluent-bit:latest
FluentBit Config has the below mentioned output config:
[OUTPUT]
  Name http
  Match *
  Host lpm-poc-1-icuskdgqpklye24nxu4jl55x4a.us-east-2.osis.amazonaws.com/
  Port 443
  URI /log-pipeline/logs
  Format json
  aws_auth true
  aws_region us-east-2
  aws_service osis
  aws_profile dev
  aws_role_arn arn:aws:iam::406205545357:role/LPM_POC_TEST_1
  Log_Level trace
  tls On

Also AWS Opensearch Ingestion Pipeline looks like this:
version: "2"
log-pipeline:
  source:
    http:
      path: "/log-pipeline/logs"

  sink:
    - opensearch:
        hosts: [ "https://vpc-logs-os-useast2-lrw5t4agewuwolew2lcatgfsfy.us-east-2.es.amazonaws.com" ]
        aws:
          sts_role_arn: "arn:aws:iam::406205545357:role/AWS_OS_Pipeline_Access_POC"
          region: us-east-2
        index: "fluent-bit"

Both the EKS cluster and Opensearch Ingestion Pipeline are in the same VPC and account. Also security group whitelisting is also done.
But fluentbit is unable to send logs and gives broken connection error.
Error:
[24/04/10 16:09:04] [error] [http_client] broken connection to lpm-poc-1-icuskdgqpklye24nxu4jl55x4a.us-east-2.osis.amazonaws.com:443 ?
[2024/04/10 16:09:04] [error] [output:http:http.0] could not flush records to lpm-poc-1-icuskdgqpklye24nxu4jl55x4a.us-east-2.osis.amazonaws.com:443 (http_do=-1)
[2024/04/10 16:09:04] [ warn] [engine] chunk '1-1712764633.904040965.flb' cannot be retried: task_id=496, input=dummy.0 > output=http.0
[2024/04/10 16:09:04] [error] [http_client] broken connection to lpm-poc-1-icuskdgqpklye24nxu4jl55x4a.us-east-2.osis.amazonaws.com:443 ?
[2024/04/10 16:09:04] [error] [output:http:http.0] could not flush records to lpm-poc-1-icuskdgqpklye24nxu4jl55x4a.us-east-2.osis.amazonaws.com:443 (http_do=-1)
[2024/04/10 16:09:04] [ warn] [engine] chunk '1-1712764635.903991891.flb' cannot be retried: task_id=1108, input=dummy.0 > output=http.0

